# Using the django-auth-ldap LDAPSearch to search two OUs

Tags: django, django-auth-ldap

I have an containerized application that is using django-auth-ldap to search an Active Directory for users. I would like to combine the output from two separate OUs. Is there a different method or overload that could take two DN's or a way to the join the output of two separate searches?

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(os.environ.get('AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASEDN', ''),
                                ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                "(sAMAccountName=%(user)s)")
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Taken from the [updated documentation](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/authentication.html#search-unions):

> New in version 1.1.
>
> If you need to search in more than one place for a user, you can use
>   LDAPSearchUnion. This takes multiple `LDAPSearch` objects and returns
>   the union of the results. The precedence of the underlying searches is
>   unspecified.

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, LDAPSearchUnion

AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearchUnion(
    LDAPSearch("ou=users,dc=example,dc=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)"),
    LDAPSearch("ou=otherusers,dc=example,dc=com", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)"),
)
```